# Count of Detail record for a Master table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a  Master Table and a Detail Table(like Categories and Products) in SQL server and  some of the Categories Do not have Products.

I want to count Products of a Category and my Where condition is like this `ProductID=100`.

In Result i want to have 0 near the Categories that have not Products and the other Categories have Products count. the result must be only for `ProductID=100` and the number off the Result is number off the Categories record.iwant to create a view and each time i run this query :

```
select * from -ViewName where ProductID=@newProductID
```

Comment: Does this have to be in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done fairly simply in a query that doesn't use views - it would be something like:

```
select c.CategoryName, count(p.ProductID)
from Category c
left join Product p 
       on c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID and p.ProductID = 100
```

Note that the condition on ProductID has to be part of the join criteria, not in the where clause, otherwise the query will only return categories that include the specified product.

This could be done fairly inefficiently in a view, by using a cross join - something like:

```
create view vwCategoryProduct as
select c.CategoryName, 
       p.ProductID,
       case when c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID then 1 else 0 end as ProductIncluded
from Category c
cross join Product p
```

- and then selecting from the view like so:

```
select * from vwCategoryProduct where ProductID = 100
```

Comment: is true and ist work.but how can i use this query to create a view and the other time only i use this query (select * from _ViewName where ProductID = newvalue
)

Comment: @Mahdijokar: I have added a view-based solution to the answer.

Comment: tnkx so mach that was want i want.tnkx every one

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
select count(p.*) as 'Number of Products'
from Categories c
left outer join Products p on c.ProductID = p.ProductID and ProductID = 100
```

Comment: Tnk soo much.but i want the other Categories that have not any Products too.like this (CAT1=0)(CAT2=2)(CAT3=0)...

Comment: NO it only list the Categories that have Products.

Comment: That's impossible, have you tried my edited answer? This last one?

Comment: i try your sql but it return only the categories  that have products.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get you on all of that

but something like

```
Select Category_Name, IsNull(Count(Products.Category_ID),0)
From Categories
Outer join Products On Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
Where Products.ProductID = 100
```

Should get you away...